# How to change my introduction

Tags: support, profile-page, network-profile

I'm trying to find the way to change my introduction in my profile, but I couldn't figure out how.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you talking about the part of your profile where it says: "I'm studying linear algebra"?

Comment: You should see an 'edit' link above the user info box, unless you are not logged in as that user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/1885989

Comment: @Qantas yes, I want to change it to another one

Answer (score 5):

Go to [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current)

Click the "edit" button:

[image]

Scroll down and edit the about me.

Comment: Awesome; hand-drawn circle on the first try! (oh; correct information, too...)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Hey, I'm an old hand at this, I'm experienced enough to do FHRCs without needing sheilding or assistance :P

Comment: @AndrewBarber true and it even looks a bit like a fish. ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I think you need to stop fishing in the nuclear waste pools ;)